# How to consume web service using WSDL file in java using IBM RAD 8.5

Tags: java, web-services, portlet, webservice-client

I am new to Webservices. We got WSDL files and we need to call its web service using IBM port lets. Someone plz help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

- First you need to know to basic idea behind `Web Services` and how it works:

  [A short introduction to Web Services](http://acs.lbl.gov/projects/gtg/projects/pyGridWare/doc/tutorial/html/x284.html)
- Then, you need to generate `Java` classes from the given `WSDL` file:

  [Creating Java Classes from WSDL file using Apache Axis 2](http://www.gerd-riesselmann.net/scala/creating-java-classes-wsdl-file-using-apache-axis-2)

  [Generating Java code from a WSDL document](http://livedocs.adobe.com/jrun/4/Programmers_Guide/ws_wsdl5.htm)

  **Note**: The reference given using `Apache Axis 2`. There are others ways to do the same task this one of them.
- Also, you need to deal with `Certificates` issue. I can not tell much about it. Since, it depends on your case.
- Now you can work with your `Java application`, where you need to establish `SSL` connection, send `requests` and receive `response` from the `Server` you are requesting services form it.

Comment: i am using RAD and Wepshere Portal Server. in that when I am generating Webservice Client then in service files i am getting error in a constructor which is expecting 3 parameters. Could you plz suggest on the same